# How come DOM objects display differently in console than general Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

For example:

```
> var a = document.getElementById('mybutton')
  undefined
> a
  <input type=​"button" id=​"mybutton" class=​"button" value=​"My Button">​
> typeof a
  "object"
> Object.getPrototypeOf(a)
  HTMLInputElement {}
> console.dir(a)
  input#mybutton.button
```

The question is then why console.log and console.dir outputs something different than the typical Class {}, and if/how can I make my own magical objects?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the Console (which has been created to work within a web browser) has special logic coded into it to make it more pleasant to work with DOM elements and integrate with other parts of the IDE (such as the web inspector). That way, there is nothing special in the DOM object itself, and it is probably not something you can hook into, at least not in a portable (cross-browser) fashion.

Comment: I think there is a way to hook into this, because jQuery objects display specially in the console.

Comment: @Barmar: Do you have an example for that?

Comment: Open the console on a web page that uses jQuery (like this one), and type `$("body")`. It displays like an array of DOM elements.

Comment: @Barmar: What browser are you using? At least on Firefox, `$('body')` displays exactly like `x = { 0: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], context: document, selector: 'body', length: 1}` (no jQuery involved in the latter).

Comment: Chrome. It displays as `[ <body class="question-page new-topbar"> ]`.

Comment: I think it's because jQuery object have a `toArray()` method. Chrome apparently calls this when displaying an object in the console.

Comment: So, what you're saying is something like "the browser natively builds the DOM and marks it so that the Console, which is built into the browser, knows to handle it specially"?

Comment: No, the "browser" (rendering and JS layer) does not do anything special. The Console knows about DOM nodes (something like `if (x instanceof Node){ specialHandling() } `)

Comment: @Barmar That is because jQuery objects **are** arrays of DOM elements.